# Need multiple people in the MailTo section in Java

Tags: java, mailto

I have a Mailto that sends an email to one person no problem. 
`String hello = "Mailto:someone@mailbomb?subject=hello%20&body=hi%20 ";`

What I need to do is to place multiple emails in the Mailto part. Example get a list of users and send it to all of them.

Is there a way to do this? I tried the following but it didn't work.
`String hello = "Mailto:" + users + "?subject=hello%20&body=hi%20 ";`

Comment: what's the content of `users`? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Following RFC6068, `users` must be an percent-encoded, comma separated list of email addresses without whitespace. Can you post the contents of the `users` variable?

Comment: this is the code that is getting the email.List<SysUser> users= new ArrayList<SysUser>();
ResultSet rsUsers = stmtUsers.executeQuery();  
  
  try {
   while (rsUsers.next()) {
    SysUser us = new SysUser();
    us.setEmail(rsUsers.getString("EMAIL"));

    users.add(us);
   }